# SSH on windows executing selenium script-> Session not created from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome, ssh, virtual-machine

Session not created from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000   (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 )

I'm doing SSH on windows virtual machine and executing selenium script on chrome browser

**My Environment:**

> Chrome Browser Version - 72
>
> Chrome Driver Version 2.46

When I locally execute selenium script directly on remote machine without SSH.Script executes successfully.Wherein when I execute script via SSH getting error.

**Error Message:**

> 'Message: session not created
>       from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
>         (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.81)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 '

**Back ground:**
whenever I execute I can see ChromeDriver.exe and Chrome browser in task manager. 
When I use the same SSH code to execute just a print python program it works successfully.Just that when it comes to selenium webdriver execution SSH fails with the error listed.

*Noted that Same selenium script works on the same browser and webdriver on another windows virtual machine.*

**What I tried:**
Tried using Chrome version 73 and 74 with their respective chrome driver.Still no success.

**My Script:**

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
cmd = ''
try:
  connectionData = client.connect(remotehost, remoteport, username, password)
except Exception as e:
  print e
transport = client.get_transport()
session = transport.open_session()
session.get_pty()
cmd = "C:\Python27\python C:\XYZ\SeleniumScript.py"
#cmd = "C:\Python27\python C:XYZ\DummyPytonPrintFile.py"
sstdin, sstdout, sstderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
output = sstdout.read()
print output
```

Comment: So this is on a windows VM? can you provide more information on how you are creating the virtual machine?

Comment: I'm not admin to this VM.

Comment: Then how are you able to change the Chrome and ChromeDriver versions on that box?  I am confused.

Comment: I've user admin sitting close to me :)